# SkiaSharp SVG image not filling screen correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have an SVG image that I want to fill the full width of my screen with. My view uses a grid. Here's my view:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--Damage view image-->
        <skia:SKCanvasView Grid.Row="0" 
                           Grid.Column="0" 
                           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                           EnableTouchEvents="True"
                           Touch="MarkDamage">
        </skia:SKCanvasView>
```

I have put my image at the top of the page, and given it 100% width and 60% height of the entire screen. Below is the method that's called when I initialize the image.

```
public void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MyClass)).Assembly;
        using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("myImage.svg");
        var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
        svg.Load(stream);

        var surface = args.Surface;
        var canvas = surface.Canvas;

        using var paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            StrokeWidth = 5,
            Color = SKColors.Orange
        };

        canvas.DrawPicture(_defaultImage.Picture, ref matrix);
}
```

However, this makes the image "overflow" on the side. Here's the result:

[image]

The right side of the image is supposed to have a little antenna sticking out, which is cut off. How do I make the image fit the screen correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize and center an SVG image based on bounding canvas/view constraints - you can use the translate and scale methods.

```
// Get drawing surface bounds
var viewInfo = args.Info;
var drawBounds = viewInfo.Rect;

// Get bounding rectangle for SVG image
var boundingBox = svg.Picture.CullRect;

// Translate and scale drawing canvas to fit SVG image
canvas.Translate(drawBounds.MidX, drawBounds.MidY);
canvas.Scale(0.9f * 
    Math.Min(drawBounds.Width / boundingBox.Width, 
        drawBounds.Height / boundingBox.Height));
canvas.Translate(-boundingBox.MidX, -boundingBox.MidY);

// Now finally draw the SVG image
canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture);

// Optional -> Reset the matrix before performing more draw operations
canvas.ResetMatrix();
```

Comment: Thanks for that, works as intended on both tablet and phone.